# Symfony2 access user from twig extension service

Tags: php, symfony, twig

When I inject the security.context in my symfony2 service (twig extension) the following error appears:

> Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object .....

```
class GeninnoShareboardExtension extends \Twig_Extension {
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container, SecurityContext $context) {
        $this->doctrine = $container->get('doctrine');
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    public function getUser() {
        return $this->context->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    ........
}
```

My services.yml looks like this:

```
services:
  geninno.twig.extension.dashboard:
    class: Geninno\EDSBundle\Twig\Extension\GeninnoShareboardExtension
    arguments:
      container: "@service_container"
      service: "@security.context"
    tags:
     - { name: twig.extension }
```

A user is logged in and my firewall setup is like this:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/secured/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secured/create, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/secured/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding an if to my SecurityContext calls.
Checking if the GetToken() returned an object (authenticated) or string (anonymous)

```
if (is_object($this->context->getToken()))
{
    .... // getUser() etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
services:
  geninno.twig.extension.dashboard:
    class: Geninno\EDSBundle\Twig\Extension\GeninnoShareboardExtension
    arguments: [@service_container, @security.context]
    tags:
     - { name: twig.extension }
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the page you are getting the error on behind a firewall?  If not then it won't have access to the security token.  You will need to put the page behind a firewall and then open it up to unauthenticated users.

something like this should do the trick to open the page up to unauthenticated users, but still have it inside a firewall (security.yml)

```
access_control:
  - { path: /lost_password, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY}
```

Comment: Thank you but all my pages are supposed to be behind a firewall, check my updated question with my firewall settings